# Making effective use of SIMD instructions without moving whole app to c++?

Tags: c#, c++, simd

I want to use SSE2 or similar instruction sets for simd to improve performance in my application.

My situation is this:

I've written some code for the app in c# but I don't mind porting if it's necessary. C# does not inherently support simd.

I have never written anything in c++, however I have written code in C before and therefore understand many of the concepts of c++ and I dont think it would be too hard to learn.

I'm looking for a practical decision on which tools to use. Do I continue with c# and interop with c++ on only performance critical functions? This wouldn't be ideal I think. Would it be better to switch to pure c++, or is there another alternative?

TLDR: I'm good with c#/java but willing to learn c++ if necessary and I need advice on what to write an app in that makes use of simd.

Comment: You'll either have to wait for [RyuJIT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrcodegeneration/archive/2014/04/03/ryujit-ctp3-how-to-use-simd.aspx) or use [Mono](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=N:Mono.Simd). It's not exactly easy right now, so first question I'd ask is: have you exhausted all other avenues of performance improvement? :)

Comment: Are there particular tasks?  Because porting to C++ for the vague reason of "simd makes things faster" is like becoming a vegetarian because you hear hawaii is nice, and there are lots of vegetarians there.

Comment: @Yakk There is one task in particular that would benefit greatly from SIMD, but the input/output to the aglorithm is fairly complex, so the interop marshalling might be a headache if i try that. Basically, i have an a list of structs as input and as output it has to change the state of an array of c# linked lists, I wouldn't even know where to begin marshalling this for interop.

Comment: You could *profile* your program to determine the bottleneck.  Write the function containing the bottleneck in C++ using SIMD.  Call the function from C#.